# How can I force another user to sign out?

Tags: macos, user-account, login, administrator

I'm the Admin user on my Mac mini but sometimes other family members use the Mac mini too with their own user/profile. Sometimes they forget to logout though.

I don't know their logins so I can't switch user and then logout for them. And even if I did know their logins, that seems like more steps than it should be. With me being the admin, surely there's something I can click to force them to logout without my having to switch users.

Comment: You can kill their `loginwindow` process from Activity Monitor or in a shell. But why do you want to do this at all?

Comment: You can set their account to logout after a time of inactivity ; Set your Mac to log out when not in use: choose Apple menu > System Settings, then click Privacy & Security in the sidebar. ... Click Advanced at the bottom. Turn on “Log out automatically after inactivity.”

Comment: @SolarMike Ah, right. If this works for the OP, please flag so we can reopen the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can kill their `loginwindow` process from Activity Monitor or in a shell, this will log them out.

They will lose any unsaved data though.